# discord webhook for github organization

Tags: github, webhooks, discord

What I find really useful and awesome about discord is how easy is to setup a webhook. I have channels dedicated just to some repos I have on github, usually inside an organization.

I realised just today that in Github you add a webhook to an entire organization and that would be great for me. like this:

[image]

But after having set up the webhook, and successfully sent some test POST (through the github UI), I see no messages in the related channel.

Is it just me with this issue?

N.B.: It doesn't give me a error when I add the webhook for the Organization.

[image]

I just don't receive the message on Discord

**EDIT:** Okay. I restricted the issue to these actions. I don't see any messages for these actions:

1. Creating a repository
2. deleting a repository

Comment: Webhook Api link has to have /github at the end of it

Comment: yes.. I did, in fact it works well with single repositories. But it seems not work with organization webhook.

Comment: Discord doesn't support all GitHub events. It supports commits, issues, comments, PRs, stars, and not much else

Comment: well I guess I got worried with no reasons then. :) 
Thank you